# Why javascript with optional chaining (?.) not work in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview

I am making an android kotlin project.

class MainActivity contains code:

```
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        val js = "test();"
        webView.evaluateJavascript(js) { result ->
            val json = JSONObject(result)
            val name_exists = json.getString("name_exists")
        }
    }
}
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

    override fun onConsoleMessage(message: ConsoleMessage): Boolean {
        Log.d("MyApplication", "${message.message()} -- From line " +
                "${message.lineNumber()} of ${message.sourceId()}")
        return true
    }
}
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html")
```

example test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function test() {
        if (options?.name != null) {
          return {
            name_exists: 'success'
          }
        }
        else{
            return {
            name_exists: 'warning'
          }
        }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get error `Unexpected token .` in line `options?.name`.

Why javascript with *optional chaining* (`?.`) not working in webview ?

Comment: How does the script inside the html know what is `option` object?

Comment: @hrystynaKb this is just an example. In this case, undefined != null. But using `?.` gives an error message.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!
Which node version are you using?
Optional chaining isn't supported until 14th

Comment: Also you can check your browser's version and if it is compatible: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

Comment: @hrystynaKb this is not node. i am trying to run this code in webview in android project on kotlin.

Comment: @LeoLoki You need to see what JS the target Android versions' WebViews support.

Comment: @DaveNewton how can i check it?

Answer (score 1):

For optional chaining Chrome version must be [80 or upper](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-80/).
WEBVIE in Android studio emulator is older than that.
i.e. my Android studio's WEBVIEW with API29 shows Chrome/74. This one can not use optional chaining. You can cneck your brouser [WhatIsMyBrowser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/) or other site.
In other hands, Actual device use newest chrome version in WEBVIEW after Android7.0(API24). Your error occurs only on android emulators.
So, you had better set your build.gradle minSdk 24 or upper and test your app in android studio with newest API.
If google play is available on the emulator, the android system WEBVIE can be updated to a newer version. That would be an effective way to solve the problem.